# Building a queue in Python

Tags: python, queue

I am trying to build a library of about 3000 IP Addresses. They will each be run through a program I have already written separately. It will scan 60 of them a day, so it needs to keep track of which is scanned and put them at the back of the queue.

I'm not looking for you to write the code, just a little bit of a push in the right direction.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but hope if this could help.

1. make a priority queue.
2. priority will be on the time-stamp on which it was accessed. 
   (if it was accessed sooner it will have less priority).

`{"ip": "time-stamp when it was accessed"}`

3. keep the queue sorted. On top you would have the least recently used ones.
4. so for 50 days you will have unique ip and after that it would repeat.
5. you could keep a list of time-stamp against each ip so you know when it accessed

   `{"ip": ["time-stamp when it was accessed", "time-stamp when it was accessed"], ...}`
6. you can use pickle or mongodb to dump and get back the data.